Zu + Verb word order
Usually, modal verbs and lassen come after the conjugated ones. For example:

Er bittet uns, ihn ausreden zu lassen.

I've never seen a specific rule about this. Can this sentence be written as

Er bittet uns zu lassen ihn ausreden.

(without the comma) or even

Er bittet uns zu lassen ihn zu ausreden?

They might be against the word order, but what specific rule is it?
Danke schön.

The natural position of verbs in a clause is at the end. Note that the order is the reverse of the English one.

(ein Kollege) der mich nicht ausreden3 lassen2 will1
will1 not let2 me speak3
(eine Geschichte) die von jemandem erfunden4 worden3 sein2 muss1
must1 have2 been3 invented4

The finite verb can be fronted.

Willst du mich vielleicht einmal ausreden lassen?
Die Geschichte muss von jemandem erfunden worden sein.

Infinitival clauses (which I will set off by square brackets) are independent units that can be moved around as a whole (note that the third variant is the least popular).

Es fällt ihm nicht immer leicht, [ mich ausreden zu lassen ].
[ Mich ausreden zu lassen ] fällt ihm nicht immer leicht.
Ihm fällt [ mich ausreden zu lassen ] nicht immer leicht.

Let's look at a modified version of the example sentence.

da er uns gebeten hat, [ ihn ausreden zu lassen ]

This is a two-clause structure. In both clauses, the verbs are in their default position. Theoretically, the whole infinitival clause could be moved inside the matrix clause.

da er uns [ ihn ausreden zu lassen ] gebeten hat

The following is out: zu lassen cannot be moved from the final position (after ausreden); only finite verbs can be fronted.

*Er hat uns gebeten, zu lassen ihn ausreden.

Since lassen governs a bare infinitive (and not a zu-infinitive), the following sentence not only violates the above word-order rule but also the requirements of lassen.

*Er hat uns gebeten, zu lassen ihn zu ausreden.


The problem with "Modalverben" in German is that the group is not all that well defined and "lassen" is the most prominent example for that. Sometimes it is used in the capacity of a Modalverb and sometimes it isn't.
The best definition (or rather: test) for "Modalverb" I can give is the following one, but I doubt its practicality, especially for non-native speakers:
When a "normal" (non-modal) verb modifies another verb, then this word is used with the infinitive. With Modalverben this infinitve stands without "zu", with all other verbs you have to use "zu":

ich wünsche zu speisen ("wünschen" = non-modal)
ich muß arbeiten ("müssen" = modal)

Following this test we get:

ich lasse arbeiten

and "lassen" would be a Modalverb according to the result. This is congruent to what I learned in school: there are seven Modalverben: "können", "mögen", "wollen", "sollen", "müssen", "dürfen" and "lassen".
There is another reasoning behind what a "Modalverb" is: if one verb modifies another then with full verbs the first one is modified by the second one:

ich beginne zu arbeiten (beginnen = non-modal)

Here the "beginnen" is describing the action and "arbeiten" just modifies the "beginnen" - it specifies what exactly it is we begin. But the unmodified first verb could stand on its own and the sentence would still be grammatical and have meaning:

Ich beginne.

With Modalverben it is the other way round: they modify the second verb:

Ich muß arbeiten.

Here "arbeiten" is the action and the "müssen" only modifies how this action is carried out - because we have to.
Here is another example showing that "brauchen" is similarly on the brink of being used as a Modalverb: there is this old saying that wer "brauchen" ohne "zu" gebraucht, braucht "brauchen" nicht zu gebrauchen, but in colloquial language you regularly will hear:

Er braucht nicht arbeiten, er ist reich genug.

After this long introduction: in your example sentence:

Er bittet uns, ihn ausreden zu lassen.

it is not the "lassen", which modifies the "ausreden", but the other way round.

Er bittet uns, ihn zu lassen.

This is a grammatical sentence and the "ausreden" is just specifiying what it is we should let him. Here "lassen" is used as a full verb and you could drop the "zu" only if "ausreden" would be a Modalverb (which it clearly isn't). The other way round it would work:

Er läßt uns ausreden.

Notice that you can use any Modalverb as a full verb too, like in the following sentence by Austrian poet Karl Kraus, reflecting on the possibility of having a revolution in 1918, when the Habsburg monarchy finally ended:

Mögen hätten wir schon wollen, aber dürfen haben wir uns nicht getraut.

It is difficult to translate, as any play on words, about: we were actually inclined to wanting, but we didn't have the heart to be allowed to.
Your other two examples are simply ungrammatical and they wouldn't work at all.

There is no modal verb in this sentence. German has these six modal verbs:

müssen, dürfen, können, sollen, wollen, mögen

Sometimes also other verbs can be used in an modal manner, but these are exceptions.
So, these are sentences with modal verbs and lassen:

Er will ihn ausreden lassen.
Er soll ihn ausreden lassen.
Er möchte ihn ausreden lassen.


As you can see, there is no »zu« in my examples. The part »ihn ausreden zu lassen« is an »Erweiterter Infinitiv mit "zu"« which works here like an object of the verb »bittet«
The verb bitten (which is NOT a modal verb) needs a subject and two objects:

subject
The subject names the person who wants something.
accusative object
The accusative object names the person to whom the request is addressed. (Who is asked to do or give something.)
prepositional object (with »um« as preposition)
The prepositional object names the thing that the subject wants from the accusative object.


Der Bettler bittet den Passanten um Geld.

But this prepositional object can be replaced by a construction that is named »zu + Infinitiv« in German grammar:

Der Wirt bittet die Gäste zu gehen.

Note, that the word »zu« can be a preposition sometimes (»Er geht zu ihr«), but this is not the case here. The word »zu« is not a preposition here, but a particle that belongs to the infinite verb. »Zu + Infiniv« is a verb-like construction. But »zu + pronoun« or »zu + nominal group« is an object-like construction (that sometimes really is an object), so it's not verb-like.
If the verb, that is used in this construction is a separable verb, then »zu« moves into the verb:

Die Gäste werden austrinken. Die Gäste trinken aus.
Der Wirt bittet die Gäste auszutrinken.

If needed, you can add extra information to that infinite verb. Then this construction is called »erweiterter Infinitiv mit "zu"« (extended infinite with "zu") which is already a sub-clause that needs to be separated from the main clause by a comma, although this subclaus is just a replacement for a prepositional object in the main clause.

Der Wirt bittet die Gäste, möglichst bald nach Hause zu gehen.
Der Wirt bittet die Gäste, ihre Getränke noch vor Mitternacht auszutrinken.

You also can add lassen to such constructions, but then the particle »zu« leaves the verb and cuddles next to lassen:

Der Verdächtige bittet den Polizisten, ihn möglichst bald nach Hause gehen zu lassen.
Walter bittet den Wirt, ihn wenigstens noch sein Bier austrinken zu lassen.


Wrong or correct?

Er bittet uns zu lassen ihn ausreden.

It's wrong. The full verb, zu and lassen must appear at the end in the construction »erweiterter Infinitiv mit "zu", and they must appear in exactly this order. And »erweiterter Infinitiv mit "zu" needs to be separated by a comma from the main clause.

Wrong or correct?

Er bittet uns zu lassen ihn zu ausreden?

Two copies of "zu" is too much! Everything said about the previous example applies here too.

Did you miss the "and" in the first sentence of the question?

@Carsten S - The use of "modal" in German is a bit awkward, being given as a list, and that's hardly a functional definition. One the one hand the definition might be according to their pattern of conjugation. But "wissen" also follows that pattern and is not considered modal. On the other hand the definition could be that it takes a bare infinitive verb as a compliment. But "lassen" fits this definition as well; the only difference is that it takes an accusative noun compliment as well. The result is that you have to add "and wissen" or "and lassen" a lot when talking about these verbs.

Thanks @Hubert Schölnast for this great didactical explanation!

To clarify (hopefully) the other answers a bit, think of "zu" as forming a new clause, and the word order in each clause is more or less independent of the word order in other clauses. Bare infinitives in German do not form a new clause, and are tacked on to the end of an existing clause. In your example, "ihn ausreden zu lassen" is what I call a "zu clause". These clauses follow their own logic which isn't quite the same as any other type of clause. First, the the "zu" + verb combination, the "zu infinitive", always appears at the end of it's clause, and the verb itself is in the infinitive. Now we have a conflict of rules when the zu clause has a second infinitive other than the zu infinitive, since both "want" to be at the end of the clause. This conflict is resolved by giving the zu infinitive priority, so a zu clause will always end with the zu infinitive even if there are other infinitives. The other infinitives are still next to last though. This situation occurs when the verb in the zu infinitive takes another (bare) infinitive as an argument. And, as you point out, only certain verbs, including the so called modal verbs and one or two others, do this. One argument for giving priority to the zu infinite is that it is the main verb in the clause, while the bare infinitive is just one of its arguments.
English, being related to German, also makes a distinction between a bare infinitive and a "to" infinitive, and which one is used depends on the main verb. For example "can" uses a bare infinitive -- "I can sing," while "like" requires a "to" infinitive -- "I like to sing." The combinations "I can to sing" and "I like sing" are both wrong, though as far as I can tell it's just historical accident that the "to" is required with one verb and prohibited with the other. Note that German and English don't always agree on which verbs use "to/zu" and which don't; "want/wollen" is an example of this.
In general, I think German zu clauses are underappreciated in terms of complexity; there's a lot more to it than just taking "zu" to mean "to".
